# Can I use external config with ASP.NET Core's default Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In the past, I've used external config files with other DI frameworks such as Unity to define the mapping of which concrete type to provide when an interface is injected.

This was a great way to fully decouple an assembly containing concrete implementations from a released copy of an application consuming them. Allowing me to load an alternative assembly simply by editing the config.

I get the impression this is just not a feature of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, especially looking through the [code](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection).

I guess I'd just like a second opinion to confirm this before I start using a different DI provider in my ASP.NET Core project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MS DI is meant to be simple, to get easily started with and which can easily be used as basis for other IoC/DI Frameworks to plug-in to it.

It doesn't has any auto-registrations, assembly scanning or decorator/interception support. If you need such features you should use a 3rd party container, like Unity which you named already.

Unity already has extension point for `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, which can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/unitycontainer/microsoft-dependency-injection) or on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection).

As documented on GitHub, all you need to do is run

```
Install-Package Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
```

To install the package and then add this to your code

> - In the WebHostBuilder add UseUnityServiceProvider(...) method
>
>   ```
>   public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
>     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
>        .UseUnityServiceProvider()    <------ Add this line
>        .UseStartup<Startup>()
>        .Build();
>   ```
> - Add method to your Startup class
>
>   ```
>   public void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
>   {
>       // Could be used to register more types
>       container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>();
>   }
>   ```

Comment: I am just trying this, however I get an exception "InvalidOperationException: No service for type &#x27;Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceProviderFactory`1[Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer]&#x27; has been registered."